# How to check in Vim why my buffers stopped working? Or how to reload Vim?

Tags: vim, buffer

Sometime when I open file and open buffer list :ls my buffer list is empty even when I had some open files before.
Then I have to quit vim and open again to get buffers works.

Is the way to restart/reload vim without closing window?

For now I know that it usually happens when I close buffer by :bd or :BD(bfkill) or maybe it can be related with closing open split window.

This is my vimrc: https://gist.github.com/1791434

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say your buffers crashed?  The only thing I can think of that would cause buffers to not be listed in `:ls` is that something is running `:bdelete` or `:bwipe` on them.

Comment: where is buffer explorer involved? I don't see where you use it

Comment: There must be a language issue here, since Vim is known for to be an ***extremelly stable program*** (I can't say I ever remember it crashing), and the concept of ***buffers crashing*** is not even known to me.

In the case of something else happening, and you losing your current editing session, there are several "mechanisms" to avoid that ... from swapfiles to backup files.

Restarting Vim is generally just that - restarting Vim, as in closing and re-opening the program. I'm afraid you'll have to clarify what you mean exactly.

Comment: So this can be releated with my plugins??

Comment: Can you post the contents of your macro files, machit.vim and editExisting.vim?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you might have `bufhidden` set to `unload`, `delete` or `wipeout`

Check that with

```
:verbose set bufhidden
```

Comment: I have not set ```bufhidden=  ```

Comment: @regedarek I didn't say `you have set it`. I guessed you might `have it set`. Did you check?